# Is linear surjective isometry always unitary?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, proof-writing

Basically what I'm trying to show is $\forall h_1, \ h_2 \in \mathscr{H}$ and $U: \mathscr{H} \rightarrow \mathscr{K}$ then $\langle Uh_1, \ Uh_2\rangle_\mathscr{K} = \langle h_1, \ h_2 \rangle_\mathscr{H}$  (So your standard definition). Now I figure the easiest way to do so is by polarization.

Since we have an isometry then

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle h_1, \ h_2 \rangle_\mathscr{H} &=& \frac{1}{4} \bigg( \|h_1 + h_2\|_\mathscr{H}- \|h_1-h_2\|_\mathscr{H} +i\|h_1+ih_2\|_\mathscr{H} - i\|h_1 - ih_2\|_\mathscr{H} \bigg)
\\&=&\frac{1}{4} \bigg( \|Uh_1 + Uh_2\|_\mathscr{K}- \|Uh_1-Uh_2\|_\mathscr{K} +i\|Uh_1+iUh_2\|_\mathscr{K} - i\|Uh_1 - Uih_2\|_\mathscr{K} \bigg)
\\&=& \langle Uh_1, \ Uh_2\rangle_\mathscr{K}
\end{eqnarray*} $

But what I'm wondering is where surjectivity comes into play?

Comment: What's your definition of unitarity? Usually, one says that $U$ is unitary iff $U^*U = U^*U = I$.

Comment: @Ronald, I think you meant $U^{*}U=UU^{*}=I$, this happens to me all the time. Cheers! OOps I see that it has been corrected. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unitary operator should also be invertible. A linear isometry is merely injective, not necessarily surjective, so you need to take on that requirement. In other words, the condition you have that $\langle Uh_1, Uh_2 \rangle = \langle h_1, h_2 \rangle$ is necessary but not sufficient for unitarity. You also want $\langle U^* h_1, U^* h_2 \rangle = \langle h_1, h_2 \rangle$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $U: \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ be an isometric and surjective operator.

We want to show that $U^* U = U U^* = I,$ i.e. the adjoint of $U$ is its inverse.

You have shown that isometry implies $\langle U h_1 , U h_2 \rangle =\langle  h_1 , h_2 \rangle$ for all $h_1,h_2 \in \mathcal{H}$. By 
$$\langle  h_1 , h_2 \rangle = \langle U h_1 , U h_2 \rangle = \langle U^*U h_1 , h_2 \rangle, $$This implies $U^* U = I,$ i.e. $U^*$ is a **left-inverse** of $U$, which implies that $U$ is injective.

Together with the surjectivity, this implies that $U$ is indeed bijective and the left-inverse coincides with the proper inverse.

Comment: May I ask you a quick question? Why do we have: $U^*$ is a left inverse of $U$ and $U$ is a bijection, so the left-inverse coincides with the proper inverse? That is, how can I show: if $U^*U = I$ and $U$ is a bijection, then we also have $UU^*=I$? Thank you.

Comment: @dh87, in case you still haven't got an answer to your question, note that if $U^{-1}$ exists and if $U^*U= I$, then we have $$UU^* =  UU^* I = UU^*(UU^{-1}) = U(U^*U)U^{-1} = UIU^{-1} = UU^{-1} = I.$$ Hope this helps.